# iOS: Create an external window that's not fullscreen?

Tags: ios, window, external-display

I'm doing an iPad app that utilizes video mirroring to mimic the content I'm putting on the iPad's display. But I'd like to add some additional content to the screen without screwing up the mirroring.

My thought was to create an external window that takes up only a portion of the screen, thereby (hopefully) leaving the "video mirror" content still visible. So I'm trying this admittedly dicey approach, and every time it "blows up" to be fullscreen (which I can see because I've set its background color to red.)

```
            CGRect externalScreenFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
            UIWindow* externalWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:externalScreenFrame];
            externalWindow.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
            externalWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            externalWindow.screen = externalScreen;
            externalWindow.hidden = NO;
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this just flat-out impossible?

Comment: Hi, have you tried what is shown in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8122073/352891

Comment: @user352891 They're creating a window that is the full size of the external display, so it's not quite the same thing. Thanks.